Apache Commons FileUpload for EE10 / Jakarta 6
I am trying to find the official version of ‘Apache Commons FileUpload’ compatible with EE 10 / Jakarta 6.
The last available version I could find on the official site is:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi
It seems that the latest version is 2.0.0-M2, which dates back to December 2023.
But after downloading the official jar, there are not the classes related to jakarta 6:org.apache.commons.fileupload2.jakarta.servlet6.*
To get the jar:
commons-fileupload2-jakarta-servlet6-2.0.0-M2.jar
which is the one that implements the Jakarta 6 specifications,
I've created a Maven project with the following dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload2-jakarta-servlet6</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
</dependency>

But looking in that jar, the date of the classes is December 2023.
In addition, it seems to me that Version M2 is a milestone (M2 = milestone 2). Or am I wrong?
In conclusion:
Does anyone know if the official 'Apache FileUpload' version that includes the implementation of the Jakarta 6 specification is available?
And why does Version M2 seem to have been stopped for about a year?
